# looping through a week of dates in Python postrgres query string and add those results to the csv datframe list

Tags: python

i have tried this but didn't work as expected

I'm connecting to a postgres sql database using python. I want to run a query for each day in a date range and append the results in a dataframe or export straight to a csv (whichever gets me the data in one place).

```
    import pandas as pd
    import pymysql
    
    from datetime import date
    dates = [
        date(year=2020, month=10, day=12), 
        date(year=2020, month=10, day=13),
        date(year=2020, month=10, day=14),
    ]
    
    conn = pymysql.connect(...)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    frame = []
    for date in dates:
        query = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = {date}""".format(date=date)
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
        frame.append(df)
   conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve all data, then create your `DataFrame`

```
values = []
for date in dates:
    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = {date}""".format(date=date))
    values.append(cursor.fetchall())
conn.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(values)
```

---

- If you cursor is not in `dictionary` mode (results are just values) you may specify the columns by yourself `df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=[])`
- Try doing  `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = %s", (date,))`, it's better to pass parameter that way toa void SQL injections